# Where have I gone wrong in trying to solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y-1}{x+4y+2}$.
Attached is a picture of my working.
Could someone please  tell me where I'm going wrong?
[image]

I'm tried both Maple and Wolfram and neither of them gives me a 'nice' answer.
I know it's wrong as I've implicitly differentiated my answer and I get the wrong algebraic value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Thanks.

Comment: From my point of view everything is correct. Could someone else make sure?

Comment: Everything is fine ! You did a great job with this problem. This just demonstrates that **you are better than a CAS** which tries to give you the analytical solution of your last equation as $y=f(x)$.

Comment: @claude did you also check the implicit differentiation ?

Comment: I also cannot find an error, perhaps the implicit differentiation was not calculated correctly.

Comment: @Peter. I refuse to check the implicit differentiation !! This is just a nightmare. Just do it with the transformed variables. Cheers.

Comment: Note that the total power of the complex looking denominator is $1$ so you can simplify further  by multiplying through by that denominator and distributing the factor $(x-2)$ between the brackets. That clears the fractions to give $|C(x-2y-4)^{\frac 34}(x+2y)^{\frac 14}|=1$ and might make the checking a little easier.

Comment: Yes, but note that the denominator has $[1-...]^{\frac{3}{4}}$ and $[1+...]^{\frac{1}{4}}$, so, surely, you can't put them as a single power (1).

Comment: @user127192 What I meant was that $(x-2)=(x-2)^{\frac 34}(x-2)^{\frac 14}$ because $\frac 34+\frac 14=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue on from my comment (and losing the absolute value signs for the moment, since we are taking fourth roots - but note the fourth roots vanish in the calculation) your complicated expression can have fractions cleared to give:

$$(x-2y-4)^{\frac 34}(x+2y)^{\frac 14}=\frac 1C$$

Implicit differentiation then gives

$$\frac 34(1-2\frac{dy}{dx})(x-2y-4)^{-\frac 14}(x+2y)^{\frac 14}+\frac 14(1+2\frac{dy}{dx})(x-2y-4)^{\frac 34}(x+2y)^{-\frac 34}=0$$ Which simplifies nicely to $$3(1-2\frac{dy}{dx})(x+2y)=-(1+2\frac{dy}{dx})(x-2y-4)$$ and gathering the terms together then gives:$$3x+6y+x-2y-4=(6x+12y-2x+4y+8)\frac {dy}{dx}$$ whence $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y-1}{x+4y+2}$$

as required (apart from being careless about signs).

Comment: Note also that raising the first expression to the power $4$ and changing the constant gives $(x-2y-4)^3(x+2y)=A$ which may be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

One trick to solve such problems somewhat explicitly is to change the parameter in such a way that the denominator is canceled.

That is, set $x=X(t)$ and $y=Y(t)=y(X(t))$ with $\dot X=X+4Y+2$ on maximal intervals where this expression is different from zero. Then

$$\dot Y(t)=\frac{dy}{dx}(X(t))\dot X(t)=\frac{x+y-1}{x+4y+2}(x+4y+2)=X+Y-1$$

and the new system is linear,

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot X(t)\\\dot Y(t)\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}X(t)\\Y(t)\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of the system matrix is $(λ-1)^2-4=(λ+1)(λ−3)$
with eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ for $λ=-1$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ for $λ=3$.

Multiplying from the left with the inverse of the eigenvector matrix (leaving out the determinant) gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}X(t)-2Y(t)\\X(t)+2Y(t)\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}-X(t)+2Y(t)\\3X(t)+6Y(t)\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $X(t)-2Y(t)=(X(0)-2Y(0)+4)e^{-t}-4$ and $X(t)+2Y(t)=(X(0)+2Y(0))e^{3t}$.

Elimination of $e^t$ from these equations results in the implicit 4th degree equation already derived,
$$
(X(0)+2Y(0))(X(0)-2Y(0)+4)^3=(X(t)+2Y(t))(X(t)-2Y(t)+4)^3
$$ 
and in the original parametrization
$$
(x_0+2y_0)(x_0-2y_0+4)^3=(x+2y(x))(x-2y(x)+4)^3
$$

One can just as well solve for $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ to obtain formulas for the trajectories,
\begin{align}
X(t)&=\tfrac12(X(0)-2Y(0)+4)e^{-t}-2+\tfrac12(X(0)+2Y(0))e^{3t}\\
Y(t)&=-\tfrac14(X(0)-2Y(0)+4)e^{-t}+1+\tfrac14(X(0)+2Y(0))e^{3t}
\end{align}

The vertical turning points of this parametrisation, where the solutions for $y(x)$ end, are solutions of
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=2X+8Y+4=3(X+2Y)-(X-2y)+4
\\
&=3(X(0)+2Y(0))e^{3t}-(X(0)-2Y(0)+4)e^{-t}+8
\end{aligned}$$
again a 4th degree polynomial in $e^t$.